# Why does wp_generate_uuid4() timeout?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'd like to generate unique titles if it's missing. When using `wp_generate_uuid4()`, it returns a `504` error. Here's the snippet of the code:

```
$custom_post = ( get_post_custom( $post->ID ) ? get_post_custom( $post->ID ) : false );
$custom_title = ( isset( $custom['name'][0] ) ? $custom['name'][0] : wp_generate_uuid4() );
```

If `wp_generate_uuid4()` is replaced with a string of text like so, it works.

```
$custom_post = ( get_post_custom( $post->ID ) ? get_post_custom( $post->ID ) : false );
$custom_title = ( isset( $custom['name'][0] ) ? $custom['name'][0] : 'Some default value' );
```

Is there any reason why `wp_generate_uuid4()` won't work?

Comment: I wondered if it was blocking on /dev/random, but at first glance the built-in version just uses mt_rand. Any chance you've got a WordPress plugin override for uuid4 that tries to make it more secure, or a PHP module that tries to make mt_rand more secure, or something like that? wp_generate_uuid4() really doesn't do much: just a few mt_rand()s and a sprintf.

Comment: @Rup, there are no other plugins besides a Gutenberg blocks plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/generateblocks/. `echo wp_generate_uuid4()` generates a UUID outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This function was introduced in WordPress 5.0, so if you're running an older version of WordPress, you won't be able to use it

Comment: it's running the latest version of WordPress.

Comment: 1. Check your server logs for any errors or warnings that might be related to the issue.


2. Try running the wp_generate_uuid4() function outside of your code to see if it generates a UUID without any errors.

`echo wp_generate_uuid4();`

Comment: there are no errors or warnings in the log file. Yes, `wp_generate_uuid4()`  generates outside the function.